# ¿Numeros aleatorios en formulario?

Tags: php, html5

Hola chicos estoy intentando hacer un formulario , el cual saca el jugador un numero al azar y luego otro con otro valor distinto pero, me pulsa uno y me dice que no esta definida y al revés también.
codigo html

[image: Pulsacion 1]

[image: Pulsación 2]

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php"> 
    <label for="jugador1">Jugador 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador1" value=""><br>
    <?php echo $dado1?>
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="DADO 1 <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>"><br><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="jugador2">Jugador 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador2" value="">
    <?php echo $dado2?> 
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="DADO 2 <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>">
</form>
```

codigo php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['btn1'])&& !isset($_GET['btn2'])){
    $jugador1 = $_GET['jugador1'];
    $jugadoractual = false;
    $dado1 = rand(1,6);
    

}else{
    if (isset($_GET['btn1'])) {
        $jugador1 = $_GET['jugador1'];
        $jugadoractual = true;
        $dado1 = rand(1,6);
        
    }if(isset($_GET['btn2'])){
        $jugador2 = $_GET['jugador1'];
        $jugadoractual = false;
        $dado2 = rand(1,6);
    }
}
```

?>

---

Hola compi gracias por responder, he puesto el código por separado pero sigue dando el mismo fallo.

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php"> 
    <label for="jugador1">Jugador 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador1" value=""><br>
    <?php echo $dado1;?>
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="DADO 1 "><br><br>
    <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="jugador2">Jugador 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador2" value="">
    <?php echo $dado2?> 
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="DADO 2 "><br>
    <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>
</form>
```

Comment: al parecer no estarías inicializando `$dado1` y `$dado2`, un `$dado1='';$dado2='';` antes de los `if _GET` debería bastar ( o testearlas antes de imprimirlas )

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿el valor de `$dado1` sería el `value` de tu `input`? Si es así, observa que estás poniendo el dato fuera de las comillas relativas a `value`, por tanto, no te admitirá nunca el valor de `$dado1` como valor del `input`. Y lo mismo pasa en los otros casos. Cada vez estoy más convencido de que la horrible mezcla de código PHP/HTML debería estar prohibida. Produce un código ilegible y confuso.

Comment: Gracias @aloMalbarez , por la respuesta, si era eso no estaba inicializando las variables dado1 y 2 antes de los if, es lo que me estaba volviendo loco, solucionado funciona perfectamente gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define las variables primero  ya que al estar adentro de un `IF ELSE` depende de la condición una variable se declara y otra no

```html
<?php 
$dado1 = "";
$dado2 = "";
$jugadoractual = false;

if(isset($_GET['btn1'])&& !isset($_GET['btn2'])){
    $jugador1 = $_GET['jugador1'];
    $jugadoractual = false;
    $dado1 = rand(1,6);
    

}else{
    if (isset($_GET['btn1'])) {
        $jugador1 = $_GET['jugador1'];
        $jugadoractual = true;
        $dado1 = rand(1,6);
        
    }if(isset($_GET['btn2'])){
        $jugador2 = $_GET['jugador1'];
        $jugadoractual = false;
        $dado2 = rand(1,6);
    }
}
?>

<form method="GET" action="index.php"> 
    <label for="jugador1">Jugador 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador1" value=""><br>
    <?php echo $dado1?>
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="DADO 1 <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>"><br><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="jugador2">Jugador 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador2" value="">
    <?php echo $dado2?> 
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="DADO 2 <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>">
</form>
```

Comment: gracias por responder, ya lo he solucionado jejeje !

Comment: comparte la solucion o puntua la respuesta que te dio la solucion

Answer (score 0):

Realiza algunos ajustes en el HTML para que veas los resultados esperados. El atributo `value` debe cerrarse con comilla `"` ,sino, se mezcla el contenido con `disabled`

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php"> 
    <label for="jugador1">Jugador 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador1" value=""><br>
    <?php echo $dado1?>
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="DADO 1" <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>"><br><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="jugador2">Jugador 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador2" value="">
    <?php echo $dado2?> 
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="DADO 2" <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>">
</form>
```